# Looking for spring-hibernate3-2.0.8 sources

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, maven-2

I'm looking for the sources jar of spring-hibernate3-2.0.8

Jarvana only has the details to the jar with the compiled classes
http://jarvana.com/jarvana/archive-details/org/springframework/spring-hibernate3/2.0.8/spring-hibernate3-2.0.8.jar

Any idea where I could find it?

I also tried mvn dependency:sources, but it couldn't find the sources in the specified, most used, repositories either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like they didn't publish sources for this artifact at this time and my suggestion would be to get the sources of the old monolithic [`spring-2.0.8-sources.jar`](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring/2.0.8/spring-2.0.8-sources.jar) (I don't think getting sources from the SVN repository and building a source jar yourself is worth it).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to the [2.0.8 tag](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-maintenance/tags/release-2-0-8/src/org/springframework/orm/) on svn.