# where is repository with spring sources

Tags: java, spring, maven

In spring and cantral repo i can find e.g. `spring-support-2.0.8.jar` but what repo should I add to my pom to make my ide automatically download sources? I don't see any repo with `spring-support-2.0.8-sources.jar`

Comment: But it is in maven central [link](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework%7Cspring-support%7C2.0.8%7Cjar)

Comment: @MarcinWiankowski No it's not! He is asking for the sources!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, not all Spring versions were deployed with sources. In a nutshell, from version 2.5, all Spring JARs come with sources.

If the source is missing, then you'll have to find it elsewhere and either add it manually to your projects or you can install a Maven mirror at your company and deploy the sources there after packaging them in a JAR file.

I suggest to try to upgrade to Spring 2.5. Newer versions of Spring are usually drop in replacements of older ones. Most of the time, the upgrade takes a couple of hours.

`spring-support` doesn't exist in Spring 2.5 anymore; the classes in there are now in `spring-context-support`.

You can use the `fc:` prefix to find the JARs which contain missing classes: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3Aorg.springframework.mail

Answer (score 0):

As [Looking for spring-hibernate3-2.0.8 sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491925/looking-for-spring-hibernate3-2-0-8-sources) mentions, the source jars were not consistently published back then. The suggestion from that question is to:

> get the sources of the old monolithic [`spring-2.0.8-sources.jar`](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring/2.0.8/spring-2.0.8-sources.jar)